# Array in input checkbox

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Newbie here. I am trying to pass array into blade checkbox value to get the id of the record or is there an other way to know the id of the particular checkbox?

Controller

```
$m = opchklst::select('id','date','task','status')
$b= $m->groupBy('task');
$a= CarbonPeriod::create($startweek,$endweek);
```

Blade View

```
@foreach ($b as $c => $r )
<tr>
<th>{{$c}}</th>
    @foreach ($a as $f)
    <td><input type="checkbox" value={{array('1','$idofrecord')}} 
name="{{$c}}[{{$f->format('Y-m-d')}}]"></input></td>
    @endforeach     
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Could you show us what is inside `$b` for better understanding what's in there as well as your desired output?

Comment: updated with controller

Comment: Thanks, now only the desired output (plain html) is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. That's my best guess:

```php
<input type="checkbox" value="{{$idofrecord[1]}}" name="{{$c}}[{{$f->format('Y-m-d')}}]"></input>
```